# Complex criteria in SUMIF

Tags: libreoffice-calc

**Is there any way, how to use "complex" criteria in the `SUMIF` function not using auxiliary calculations?**

I would like to sum expenses per month having following (autogenerated) input:

```
  |      A          B
--+----------------------
1 |   2016-10-03    111
2 |   2016-10-12    2300
3 |   2016-11-05    500
4 |   2016-11-17    1000
```

So, looking for formulas, probably utilizing `SUMIF`, for construction on following report (the year `$C$1` and month `$D1` are inputs required to be in separate cells and used by the calculation):

```
   |    C      D        E
 --+-----------------------
   |                 +----+
 1 |   2016    1     |0   |
 2 |           2     |0   |
   |   ...           |    |
10 |           10    |2411|
11 |           11    |1500|
12 |           12    |0   |
                     +----+
```

E.g.: Expecting formula for E1 like `=SUMIF(A1:A4; And(Year(???) = $C$1; Month(???) = $D1); D1:12)`

I'm able to calculate the Month/Year predicates for all input rows and base the `SUMIF` on it, but it requires another level of maintenance which is not desired.

I was experimenting a bit and searching the help, but looks like the criteria is more textual than formula/function friendly, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I Dont know if this will help your situation. My problem was I have a worksheet with payments out. It has the date in column A and the cost in column B. I wanted to know how much was spent each month. I have set it out in the same way as your problem to show how I got over it.

```
   |    A            B            C
------------------------------------------
1  | 2016/10/03      111    2016/10/01
2  | 2016/10/12      2300   2016/11/01
3  | 2016/11/05      500    2016/12/01
4  | 2016/11/17      1000   2017/01/01
```

I had been puzzeling over my similar problem for some time and could not find anything online so kept trying all sorts of ways untill I came up with this.

I put the date of the first of the month I wanted in an unused cell (C1) then put the first of the next month in to the cell below it (C2) and so on.

```
   |    A            B            C
------------------------------------------
1  | 2016/10/03      111    2016/10/01
2  | 2016/10/12      2300   2016/11/01
3  | 2016/11/05      500    2016/12/01
4  | 2016/11/17      1000   2017/01/01
```

then my formula for my first month is.

=SUMIFS( B1:B4, A1:A4, ">="&C1, A1:A4, "<"&C2)

and my formula for next month is.

=SUMIFS( B1:B4, A1:A4, ">="&C2, A1:A4, "<"&C3)

SUMIFS() As I see it, sums the contents of cells in a range of cells based on more than one condition to be met.

The first part of the formula, B1:B4, is the range of cells containing the costs that need to be summed if all conditions are true.

The second part of the formula, A1:A4, is the range containing the dates of the costs pertaining to the second criteria to be met.

The third part of the formula, ">="&C1, is the first criteria that must be met (The date is higher than or equal to the date in C1).

The fourth part of the formula,A1:A4, is the range containing the dates of the costs pertaining to the second criteria to be met (which is the same range of dates as the first condition to be met).

The fifth and last part of the formula, "<"&C2, is the second criteria that must be met (The date is lower than the date in C2).

If someone has a better way please let us know